# django-haystack: Predicting facets

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am trying to see if the [django-haystack](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html) is good for my faceting needs. Currently I want to display number near my facets. Lets say we have a model shown in their docs, but with an extra field for faceting (e.g. style in which author writes notes... e.g. styles are classic or modern). So index will look like this.

```
class NoteIndex(SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = CharField(model_attr='user', faceted=True)
    style = CharField(model_attr='style', faceted=True)
    pub_date = DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')
```

Now I make a search query set, and narrowing to facet author e.g. john. Now I want to display estimation on how many products will appear if I will select another author together with John (e.g. +10 articles). Also same question about adding an extra facet from styles... How do I do this. Search BE is elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [facet_counts](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/searchqueryset_api.html#facet-counts) method of SearchQuerySet does what you want:

```
results = SearchQuerySet().filter(text='some product').facet('author')
counts = results.facet_counts()
author_results = counts['fields']['author']
author_counts = {author: num_products for author, num_products in author_results}
```

Then, you can sum up the number of products by John and the number of products by another author. That will give you the number of products if you were to broaden the search to both of them:

```
num_john_products = author_counts.get('John', 0)
num_bob_products = author_counts.get('Bob', 0)
total = num_john_products + num_bob_products
```

Or, you could even find the author other than John with the most products, and show the number of results if you were to also include that author in the search:

```
author_counts.pop('John')
most_popular_author = max([(count, author) for author, count in author_counts])
count, author = most_popular_author
total_john_and_most_popular = num_john_products + count
```

Comment: that helps a lot. but what if i have another facet. e.g style .. my narrow looks like this attributes_exact:(color-white OR color-silver) AND (style-gothic OR style-traditional)... e.g. it can be refined by color and by style after that...

Comment: For more complex queries like that, you can use the [query_facet](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/searchqueryset_api.html#SearchQuerySet.query_facet) method. It's backend specific, so you'd need to use elasticsearch query syntax in the 'query' argument.

Comment: Could you give an example of how that might be used... E.g. I have facets author and style. Selected author John and style classic and modern. Now I would like to see how many items will be added if I will also select another author 'Jack'

Comment: It would look something like `results = SearchQuerySet().query_facet('style', 'classic OR modern').facet('author')`. Then you'd follow the same procedure with facet_counts() as I described above.